# Cant set layer visible

Tags: jquery, dictionary, if-statement, visible

I am making an interactive map and I am having issues turning a layer on and off. I can get to turn off, I just cant get it to turn back on.

```
$(function() {
    $("#BS").click(function () {
       if (avenzaViewer.isLayerVisible("BuyingScrapple"))
            avenzaViewer.setVisible("BuyingScrapple", true); 
        else
            avenzaViewer.setVisible("BuyingScrapple", false); 
    });
});
```

When I open https://www.jamiehamill.net/Delaware1.html and click on `Buying Scrapple`, the icons related to that layer disappear. However, when clicking it again, they don't reappear as they should.

Comment: I checked your link and it says `if (avenzaViewer.setVisible("BuyingScrapple", true))` instead of `isLayerVisible`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time with this. I just uploaded the correct version.